# C++ error: request for member … which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, templates, generics, set, generic-programming

I've tried looking at other similar questions, but they all seem to contain answers regarding a feature of c11 I'm using.

When running the following code I get the error:

> error: request for member 'current' in
>   '*((mtm::MtmSet*)this)->mtm::MtmSet::it.mtm::MtmSet::iterator::operator->()', which is of non-class type 'const int'
>                it->current = NULL;

in several parts of my MtmSet.h file.

These are the files I'm using. I'm truly at loss, so I fear I don't know which part is relevant, but have tried to omit as much as possible.
Error lines are marked Bold+Underline.

main.cpp:

```
#include "MtmSet.h"

int main() {
    MtmSet<int> set;
    return 0;
}
```

MtmSet.h:

```
#ifndef MTM4_SET_H
#define MTM4_SET_H

#include <cstdlib>

namespace mtm{


    template<typename Type>
    class MtmSet{

        /**
         * A node in the set
         */
        class Node{
            Type data;
            Node* next;

        public:
            Type& getData() {
                return data;
            }
            Node getNext() {
                return *next;
            }

            Node() = default;
            explicit Node(Type data) : data(data), next(NULL) {}
        };

        Node* first;

    public:

        //Forward declaration
        class const_iterator;

        /**
         * A iterator for Set
        */
        class iterator{
            Node* current;
        public:
            /**
             * Empty constructor. Should not be dereferenced.
             * Same as MtmSet::end()
             */
            iterator() = default;

            /**
             * Constructor of Set iterator
             * @param node The node the iterator points to
             */
            explicit iterator(Node *node){
                current = node;
            }

            /**
             * Copy constructor
             * @param it The iterator to copy
             */
            iterator(const iterator& it){
                *this = it;
            }

            /**
             * Destructor
             */
            ~iterator() = default;

            iterator& operator=(const iterator& rhs){
                current = rhs.current;

                return *this;
            }

            const Type& operator*() const{
                return current->getData();
            }

            const Type *operator->() const{
                return current->getData();
            }

            iterator& operator++(){
                *current = current->getNext();
                return *this;
            }

            iterator operator++(int){
                iterator it = *this;
                *current = current->getNext();
                return it;
            }

            bool operator==(const const_iterator& rhs) const{
                if (current == rhs.current) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rhs) const{
                return !(current == rhs.current);
            }

            friend class const_iterator;
        };

        iterator it;
        const_iterator const_it;

        /**
         * Empty constructor
         * Creates an empty set
         */
        MtmSet() : first(NULL){
```

First Error on it->current = NULL, and const_it->current = NULL below,
while all other lines return the same error:

```
            it->current = NULL;
            const_it->current = NULL;
        }

        /**
         * Copy constructor
         * @param set the Set to copy
         */
        MtmSet(const MtmSet& set){}

        /**
         * Destructor
         * Free all allocated memory in the set.
         */
        ~MtmSet() = default;

        iterator insert(const Type& elem){
            Node *a = new Node(elem);
            if (first == NULL) {
                first = a;
                const_it->current = a;
                it->current = a;
                return it;
            }

            if (contains(elem)) {
                return it;
            }

            while (it->current->next != NULL) {

                it->current = it->current->next;
            }
            it->current->next = a;
            it->current = it->current->next;

            return it;
        }

        iterator find(const Type& elem){}

        const_iterator find(const Type& elem) const{
            it->current = first;

            while (it->current != NULL) {
                if (it->current->data == elem) {
                    return it;
                }
            }
            return NULL;
        }

        bool contains(const Type& elem) const{
            if (find(elem)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
} // namespace mtm

#endif //MTM4_SET_H
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++. Use `nullptr`. Also, return `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `main`, not `0`.

Comment: Where is it defined?

Comment: First help: Reproduce the issue in isolation. In particular, extract a minimal example which you could then post here. As it stands, the lack of an MCVE makes your question off-topic.

Comment: He *did* reproduce the issue and post a minimal example here.  One can easily make a sample application from what he posted above.  His question is not off topic.

Comment: Osmosis, I can't exactly reproduce your error but trying that out in MS Visual C++, it complains about the type "const_iterator" for obvious reasons;  All you've done is forward-declared it.  You've never defined it.  Then you try to use it.  That's never going to work.

Comment: I did define it, I just omitted it, as it is irrelevant for the error, apparent by the error's first instance occurring before its first use.

Comment: In that case, I retract my erroneous reply to Ulrich.  Sorry Ulrich.  Osmosis, you need something that people can reproduce or we waste time tracking down errors that aren't there, as I just did.

And the fact that the compiler reports an error before it is defined is irrelevant, by the way.  Errors are not always reported as you might expect

Comment: You may need to declare MtmSet<int> set; as mtm::MtmSet<int> set;

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the problem is that operator->() of iterator is the const method, and it calls method Node::getData() which is not const. But, your code does not contains const_iterator class and does not compile, so I don't know maybe there is another problem